# Outsystems - Add another environment

Tags: development-environment, outsystems

I previously created a personal environment in Outsystems 11, I need to create a new one in Outsytems 10 because it is the version I needed. I searched over the internet and saw how to add another environment in Lifetime cloud but the options in my environment management looks like this only.

[image]

How can I add a new environment? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain why you would need a P10 personal environment specifically?

Answer (score 5):

In a Personal Environment you can have only one stage/environment. Adding other stages is only available on paid subscriptions.

In any case, it's no longer possible to launch new version 10 infrastructures. Only v11 infras are now available.

Answer (score 1):

Like Miguel said, only paid subscriptions can have multiple environments, and each environment is paid. Also personal environments have the last version of the platform. Only creating another account, to have a new environment.